# How to include files relative to a file's directory

Tags: plugins, php, themes

I'm building a small plugin into a WordPress theme like `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin`.

I'm wondering how to include files inside this folder that are relative to the main plugin file `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/my-plugin.php`.

For example, in `my-plugin.php`, I need to include `wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin/css/style.css`.

I'm looking for something like `wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin-style', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );` but I want it to be only relative to the `my-plugin.php` directory and NOT relative to the WordPress plugin directory OR theme directory. This way I can make it a separate plugin too if I want, without changing any code.

Please do not ask why I'm building this into the theme or that it should be a separate plugin. Just looking for possible solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plugin within a theme - sounds like something new. You might not find function in this context. Let's create ours:

```
<?php
/**
 * Get My Plugin URL.
 * @return string.
 */
function wpse295740_get_plugin_url() {
    // http://example.com/wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin
    return get_template_directory_uri() .'/inc/my-plugin';
}

/**
 * Get My Plugin Path.
 * @return string.
 */
function wpse295740_get_plugin_path() {
    // eg. /home/user/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/themes/my-theme/inc/my-plugin
    return get_template_directory() .'/inc/my-plugin';
}
```

You can make it more complex using the `__FILE__` magic constant etc. - see the original [`plugin_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugins_url/) source. And [`plugin_dir_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/plugin_dir_path/) too. And [`trailingslashit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/trailingslashit/) and [`untrailingslashit()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/untrailingslashit/) are there too for ease.